# What does if (variable) mean in C language?

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm currently preparing for gate; I have come across a question

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    static int var=6;
    printf("%d\t",var--);
    if(var)
        main();
}
```

The output is 6 5 4 3 2 1

I wanna know why it terminated after 1?

Comment: Note that Standard C has required an [explicit return type for `main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/15168) — and it should be `int` — for the whole of the current millennium.  Use `int main(void)` unless you're going to use the command line arguments, in which case use `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or equivalent.

Comment: The question seems to be using code from a document [C Sample Technical Questions](https://www.scribd.com/document/222587837/C-Sample-Technical-Questions) claiming that memorizing such trivia will make you successful in a job interview. The easiest way to pass a technical interview is to *learn* the language, preferably from a **book**, and use it, before going to an interview.

Comment: `if(x)` is equivalent to `if ( x != 0 )`

Answer (score 2):

An `if` statement always tests to see if the expression inside the parentheses evaluates to true.

In this case, `var` is an positive integer, so it evaluates to `true`. Since 0 always evaluates to `false`, as soon as `var = 0` the `if` statement evaluates to `false` and the loop exits.

Note that `if(var)` is not specific to C (re the question title), it applies to many languages.

Comment: "All languages" is a sweeping claim — I'd dispute that it applies to Pascal, for instance.  It applies to many languages, especially those influenced by C, but "all" is not justifiable.  (Pascal would only allow `if var then` (parentheses not required) if `var` is of type `boolean`; C is far more generous about which types can appear in the condition, allowing any scalar type to be used.)

Comment: You used 'loop' for the recursion too — see my notes to what is currently the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59551052/15168).

Answer (score 0):

`if (var)` checks whether `var` is not zero! If `var` is zero it finish.

Comment: An `if` statement is not a loop.  Maybe you should say "If `var` is zero, it skips the body of the `if` statement, going to the `else` clause if there is one", or something similar.

Comment: yes it is not loop but it calls recursive function if its true

Comment: Being sloppy in your terminology won't get you credit on SO.  You need to be careful and precise.  Recursion is also not a a loop.  You're right that recursion is involved, and it's simple tail recursion, so it could be replaced by a loop.  But it is not itself a loop — there is no `for`, `while` or `do … while` involved (nor `goto`, but that's a whole separate bag'o'worms!).